# Is the soundcloud html5 widget iframe styleable via css?

Tags: css, iframe, soundcloud

I'd like to use the html5 widget + it's api (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/html5-widget)
My question: can tha widget be styled via CSS? FireBug shows style information, once the player is loaded, and I'm wondering, if it is possible to change those styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The widget is inserted into the page in an iframe and I don't think it's possible to change the styles inside an iframe from outside. The only "styling" which is catered for is changing the colour of the buttons and waveform, via the "color" url parameter.

For example, here's a user's sounds widget with pretty pink buttons and waveform highlights:

http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2F2&show_artwork=true&show_comments=false&color=ff00ff&show_playcount=false&liking=false

Here's the url reformatted for legibility:

```
http://w.soundcloud.com/player/
?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2F2
&show_artwork=true
&show_comments=false
&color=ff00ff    <-----
&show_playcount=false
&liking=false
```

Comment: How do you style it with the URL parameter? Would you mind adding an example to your answer?

Comment: it is styleable using javascript

Answer (score 1):

That guy did it using SoundCloud API, some JavaScript and CSS:

http://codepen.io/nickcolley/pen/uoCIy

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var player = SC.Widget($('iframe.sc-widget')[0]);
  var pOffset = $('.player').offset();
  var pWidth = $('.player').width();
  var scrub;

  player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
    setInfo();
    player.play();
  }); //Set info on load

  player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, function(e) {
    if( e.relativePosition < 0.003 ) { setInfo(); }
    //Event listener when track is playing
    $('.position').css('width', ( e.relativePosition*100)+"%");
  });

   $('.player').mousemove(function(e){ //Get position of mouse for scrubbing
    scrub = (e.pageX-pOffset.left);
  });

  $(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
      case 32:
        player.toggle(); 
      break;
      case 39:
        player.next();
      break;
      case 37:
        player.prev();
      break;
    }
  });

  $('.player').click(function(){ //Use the position to seek when clicked
    $('.position').css('width',scrub+"px");
    var seek = player.duration*(scrub/pWidth); 

    //Seeking to the start would be a previous?
    if ( seek < player.duration * .05 ) {
      player.prev();
    } else if ( seek > player.duration * .99 ) {
      player.next();
    } else {      
      player.seekTo(seek);
    }

  });

   function setInfo() {
    player.getCurrentSound(function(song) {
      console.log(song);

      $('.waveform').css('background-image', "url('" + song.waveform_url + "')");    
      $('.player').css('background-image', "url('" + song.artwork_url.replace('-large', '-t500x500') + "')");

      var info = song.title;
      $('.info').html(info);

      player.current = song;
    });

    player.getDuration(function(value){
      player.duration = value;
    });

    player.isPaused(function(bool){
      player.getPaused = bool;
    });
  }   

});
```